# Jquery selectors on ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I receive ajax response as html, and I need to extract content of specified div.

It works:

```
function callback(data) {
    container = $(data).filter('div.container#container');
    container_in = $(container.html()).filter('div.container-in');
    main_container = $(container_in.html()).filter('div#main-container.main-container');
    div_content = $(main_container.html()).filter('div#content.right-block');
}
```

and it return empty

```
$(data).filter('div#content.right-block')
```

Can I use one selector on $(data) however?

Comment: Dump the data into a div and then apply selector  `$('someDIV').html(data)` and then use your code

Comment: Can you post what console.log(data) returns?

Comment: You probably should be using `find`, not `filter`.

Comment: @freshbm: console.log(data) return pure html.

Comment: @asifsid88: not beautiful solution, I think.

Comment: @indapublic Put `@` before names, not `2`, to notify people that you're replying.

Comment: @Barmar: why find is better than filter?

Comment: `find` searches the DOM for the element, `filter` reduces a list of elements to the ones that match, but it doesn't look inside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function callback(data) {
    container = $(data).find('#container');
    container_in = container.find('div.container-in');
    main_container = container_in.find('#main-container');
    div_content = main_container.find('#content');
}
```

You don't need to keep using `.html()` and `$()`, because the first `$(data)` parses everything into DOM elements. Also, extra tag and class qualifiers on ID selectors are redundant, since IDs are required to be unique.

You can also get to the content with a single selector:

```
div_content = $(data).find("#content");
```